# Отключить прокрутку под виджет (CupertinoSliverNB) - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Ситуация такая, использую CupertinoSliverNavigationBar, настроил его "под себя" (именно в файлах самого фреймворка, увеличил отступ слева, убрал нижнюю тень, увеличил немного шрифты), всё бы ничего, но меня не устраивает, что контент прокручивается под сам виджет и, честно сказать, выглядит стрёмно. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно "ограничить прокрутку"?
P.S. 1 скриншот - "развёрнутое" состояние, а 2 - "свёрнутое" состояние. 3 скриншот - чего хотелось бы добиться в итоге (сейчас этого можно добиться, если прокрутить не "до упора").

**Скриншот 1:**
[image: Скриншот 1]

**Скриншот 2:**
[image: Скриншот 2]

**Скриншот 3:**
[image: Скриншот 3]

Comment: Очевидно до-настроить "под себя" или написать свой NavigationBar...

Comment: @MiT пытался, я не нашёл файла (класса) отвечающего за поведение прокрутки при использовании NavigationBar'а. Может, если Вы знаете, дадите наводку?

Comment: SliverPersistentHeader и _LargeTitleNavigationBarSliverDelegate за это отвечают.